# Colorbox inline style="display:none" doesn't disappear

Tags: javascript

I am using colorbox module. 
I have an inline modal that works o.k, this is the code:

```
<a class="colorbox-inline" href="?width=310&amp;height=460&amp;inline=true#paste-data-to-lp">view content</a>

<div class="colorbox-inline" id="paste-data-to-lp" style="display: none;">
  <pre>
    <input name="name" type="name" />
    <input name="phone" type="phone" />
    <input name="email" type="email" />
  </pre>
</div>
```

This code is an a view header.

When I click the link the modal pops but it is empty. 
I've noticed that the `style="display: none;"` in the div does not disappear.

What can cause this?

Any help will be great.

Comment: is there any javascript that attached that attribute? or hardcoded in the tpl?

Comment: no... not as much as i know... this is a new drupal installation with some modules

Answer (score -1):

O.k... I changed the code to this and it works...

```
<a class="colorbox-inline" href="?width=500&height=500&inline=true#id-of-content">Link to click</a>

    <div style="display: none;">
    <div id="id-of-content">
     <pre>
        <input name="name" type="name" />
        <input name="phone" type="phone" />
        <input name="email" type="email" />
      </pre>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The other way would be .view-header #paste-data-to-lp { display: none; } . You just need to narrow down where you hide it. It's generally recommended that you do styling with an external css file so your styles don't have to be configured in the UI.